# how to convert unity engine converted android project into x86 format

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, x86, apk

I had converted my unity 3d game file as google android project. Then tried to convert that file into x86 format with all the prerequisite methods from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/using-the-android-x86-ndk-with-eclipse-and-porting-an-ndk-sample-app .
It was successful while building apk file, but when I run it, it crashes, showing "Application stopped unfortunately.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

Unity is not yet supported for Android x86 platforms. Any APK using unity lib files cannot be recompiled to x86 at this point in time.